# Is it still possible to use django-mediagenerator on Google App Engine

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-nonrel, django-mediagenerator

I've been working on a existing project at a new company and one of the problems we're running into is Javascript code duplication. We're working in Google App Engine, and I have heard of the [Django media generator asset manager](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-mediagenerator) which seems like it could solve some of our problems. However, after reading through the docs on that page and pages [like this one on running Django in Google App Engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/django), I'm not sure if it is even possible to run django-mediagenerator on Google App engine.

Is it still possible to use django-mediagenerator on Google App Engine? Has the project gone stale? Is there some other media generator that I should be using in app engine?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django-mediagenerator is developed with app-engine in mind, as you can see in [this blog post](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/blog/django/2010/08/django-mediagenerator-total-asset-management).

So : yes you can go with it ;-)

Comment: The blog post is nearly two years old though, and refers to app-engine setups using app-engine-patch (discontinued) or django-nonrel (which [has not been maintained](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/goodbye) [in almost a year](https://bitbucket.org/Wilfred/django-nonrel))

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative I've had some success using [webassets](https://github.com/miracle2k/webassets) as an asset manager in Google App Engine, although because of the limitations of the production environment its a command line process before deployment.

There's a basic app engine example in the repository, so it's fairly quick to setup.